# PSQL - Modifying JSONB element

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb object like this:

```
{
  "members": [
    [
      "1966-07-31",
      null,
      {
        "last_name": "ss",
        "first_name": "ss"
      }
    ],
    [
      "1968-12-17",
      "spouse",
      {
        "last_name": "kk",
        "first_name": "kk"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to convert it to.

```
{
  "applicants": [
    {
      "last_name": "ss",
      "first_name": "ss"
    }
    {
      "last_name": "kk",
      "first_name": "kk"
    }
  ]
}
```

Essentially taking the third element of each member and putting is an object in a new array 'applicant'. I don't need the member data that is outside the object.

I can run a PHP script to loop through all the rows and update it. But I'm wondering if I can write this in plain sql query?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html? Try to use `jsonb_agg` and `jsonb_array_elements`. Or alternatively, `jsonb_path_query_array`

Comment: Do you always have two elements in the `members` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `jsonb_array_elements` with two `CROSS JOIN` for extract JSON array data then aggregate them

**Dynamic array**:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=10de054c854b3e92ab2a75a248174399)

```sql
select
  jsonb_build_object('applicants', jsonb_agg(e2.value))
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.obj -> 'members') as e1
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(e1.value) as e2
where 
  e2.value ? 'first_name'
  and e2.value ? 'last_name'
```

---

**Static array**:

If your structure is specific you don't need a loop over the array and can use the below query:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bf74d24e221c3fd4c6e8d4d16d24f1b9)

```sql
select
  jsonb_build_object('applicants', jsonb_agg(e1.value -> 2))
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.obj -> 'members') as e1
```

Comment: No need to loop over `e1.value`, just use `e1.value -> 2`

Comment: How do you know this object exist in index two, It was unstructured data and maybe exist in any index of array

Comment: The values in the OP's example appear to be tuples with fixed length, types, and order. OP asked for "*taking the third element of each member*".

Comment: Yes all the entries are configured the same, with the third element being an object

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The end goal was to update the rows with the new structure, but this helped me get there.